# Showing different directories in multiple netrw instances

Tags: netrw, multiple-files

I was hoping that I could have splits or tabs in which I would use different netrw instances to see different folders or to use separate hide lists. Unfortunately any change in split/tab A affects what netrw in split/tab B shows.

Is there any way to have multiple netrw views (unaffected by each other)?

If not, could I achieve similar effect by executing some commands when split/tab gets focus? If so, can I expect some negative side effects?

I'm using VIM 8.2 on Ubuntu-20.04 through Windows 10 WSL.

**Update**: I've checked in VIM 8.2 on Windows Git Bash and netrw works correctly, meaning I can have netrw in one split showing different directories than netrw in another split.

**Update 2**: I've disabled non-default plugins and checked my `.vimrc` and it turned out that on Ubuntu I had `let g:netrw_liststyle=3` option (tree view) set. Tree view clearly shows that if I go into a folder in one split it instantly affects the folder shown by netrw in another split.

I've also checked what happens if I  hide dot-files in one split - it changes what's visible in another split. So it seems that indeed, there's only a single instance of netrw shared across all splits/tabs and my original question still stands. It's just the tree view makes this fact instantly obvious when you move between folders.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I don't follow... I tried two separate netrw splits and they each get their own directory... Can you describe an example of how to reproduce the issue you're seeing? Perhaps a few steps, what's the behavior you see and what you would expect? Can you reproduce it under `vim --clean`, which will not load plug-ins and your customizations from your vimrc? Perhaps you have an option enabled which triggers the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: You are right, it seems this is either config or WSL issue (I've updated the post). Isn't `vim --clean` a bit too clean (netrw is a plugin too)?

Comment: The struggle continues (Update 2 added)